# Динамическое рисование дуги canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Можно ли как-то плавно динамически рисовать дугу? Есть такой код:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('cnvs');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.lineWidth = 15;
ctx.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
ctx.lineCap = "round";

ctx.arc(100, 100, 80, 2.355, 7.065, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="cnvs" width="400px" height="400px"></canvas>
```

Но он рисует дугу сразу, а мне хотелось бы, чтобы оно рисовало ее с нуля и достигало нужного значения за 1-2 сек. Такое возможно функциями `canvas`? Или надо использовать что-то другое?

Comment: Для примера: https://jsfiddle.net/umaar/fnMvf/

Comment: а в чём проблема-то? анимация так и устроена: рисуешь кадр, потом всё стираешь, рисуешь следующий кадр. Просто нужно плавно менять значения передаваемые в функцию `arc`